# Extensions of groups with a $G$-action

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, group-cohomology, galois-cohomology

Let $1\longrightarrow A\longrightarrow \mathcal{G}\longrightarrow R\longrightarrow 1$ be an exact sequence of algebraic group schemes, with $\mathcal{G}$ being an extension of $R$, an affine reductive group scheme, by $A$, an affine abelian unipotent group scheme. All group schemes are over $\mathbb{Q}$.

It is well known that any central extension of an affine group scheme splits, so that we have $\mathcal{G} = A\rtimes R$.

Assume all groups are equipped with a $G$ action, where $G$ is the absolute Galois group of the rationals, and that the sequence is Galois equivariant in the sense that if the map $\mathcal{G}\longrightarrow R$ is called $\pi$, then for ever $h\in G$ and $g\in \mathcal{G}$, one has $\pi({}^hg) = {}^h\pi(g)$.

Is it true that there necessarily exists a Galois equivariant splitting $\mathcal{G} = A\rtimes R$, i.e., a splitting $s: R\longrightarrow \mathcal{G}$, for which  for every $r\in R$ and $h\in G$, one has:

$${}^hs(r) = s({}^hr).$$

Thanks in advance.

P.S.

Although I do not know of a counter example to the above statement, I am more interested to know if, in the particular situation that I am interested in, where $R = \text{SL}_2$, and $A$ is a free abelian group, this holds for whatever reason.

Also, I imagine that there should be some cohomological criterion for deciding whether a $G$-equivariant exact sequence has a $G$-equivariant splitting, so I would be interested to know what this criterion is.

Comment: $\newcommand\aQ{\overline{\mathbb Q}}$Since $R = \operatorname{SL}_2$ is simply connected, I suspect that the answer in that case will be much nicer than in the general case.  If we knew that $R(\aQ)$ acted transitively on the splittings of $\mathcal G_{\aQ}$, then this would become, as you suspect, a cohomology question; but I don't know if that is what happens.

Comment: Given any section $s: R\longrightarrow \mathcal{G}$, and an element $a\in A$, $a\cdot s: r\mapsto a\cdot s(r)$ is another section. I believe it is a corollary of the Levi decomposition theorem that in my case $A$, with this action, acts transitively on the set of splittings.

Comment: [Re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/451883/extensions-of-groups-with-a-g-action#comment1168409_451883), are your splittings not meant to be group homomorphisms?  If they are meant to be, then I don't see how $r \mapsto a\cdot s(r)$ is one.  (Oh, wait, I now see that you refer to [central extensions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_extension#Central_extension) … but also to $\mathcal G = A \rtimes R$.  In the terminology with which I am familiar, the only central semi-direct product extension is the direct product.)

Comment: You are right, I meant $r\mapsto as(r)a^{-1}$.

Comment: [Re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/451883/extensions-of-groups-with-a-g-action#comment1168412_451883), OK.  I misread and thought you were considering splittings $\mathcal G \to A$, for which the conjugation action by $\mathcal G$ is trivial when restricted to $A$, so that it factors through an action of $R$.  (But am I misunderstanding also about [central extensions](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/451883/extensions-of-groups-with-a-g-action#comment1168411_451883)?)

Comment: A central extension is an extension of a group by a commutative group. If $(a_1,r_1)$ and $(a_2, r_2)$ are two elements of $\mathcal{G}$, written in the coordinates of some splitting $s: R\longrightarrow \mathcal{G}$, then $(a_1,r_1)\cdot (a_2,r_2) = (a_1\cdot(r_1 a_2 r_1^{-1}), r_1r_2)$, Were it the direct product, $r_1a_2r_1^{-1}$ was equal to $a_2$, which would hold in case $a_2$ was in the center of $\mathcal{G}$, but a central extension of $R$ by $A$ doesn't mean $A\le Z(\mathcal{G})$, but rather that $A$ is commutative. Sorry if this was too trivial.

Comment: [Re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/451883/extensions-of-groups-with-a-g-action#comment1168417_451883), I don't think that "A central extension is an extension of a group by a commutative group" is the usual definition; for example, it's not the one on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_extension#Central_extension), which is the same as the one in Weibel, §6.9, both of which require that the image of the commutative subgroup actually lie in the centre of $G$.

Comment: Also, I am sceptical that, even with the restrictive definition of 'central extension', every central extension of an affine, even semisimple, group scheme splits. For example, I believe that $\operatorname Z(\operatorname{GL}_2) \to \operatorname{GL}_2 \to \operatorname{PGL}_2$ does not (at least as groups, which seems to be what you are using); if it did, then there would be a morphism $\operatorname{PGL}_2 \to \operatorname{GL}_2$, landing by semisimplicity in $\operatorname{SL}_2$, but the only morphism $\operatorname{PGL}_2 \to \operatorname{SL}_2$ is trivial.  Could you give a reference?

Comment: Are you familiar with the works of Cegarra--Garcia-Calcines--Ortega and of Inassaridze on equivariant group cohomology? They give isomorphisms between the equivalence classes of extensions of $G$-groups with kernel $A$ and quotient $\mathcal{G}$ with certain equivariant cohomology groups $H^2_G(\mathcal{G};A)$. In Inassaridze's case, the extensions are assumed to be $G$-split. I'm a bit familiar with these works, but I'm afraid I don't understand the set-up of your question well enough to see if they apply (I've the same confusion about the definition of *central* as LSpice).

Comment: Concerning your setup:: You see that $A$ is an abelian unipotent group scheme over $\Bbb Q$.  An after that you write that you are interested in the particular case when $A$ is a free abelian group.  How can a free abelian group be an abelian unipotent group scheme over $\Bbb Q$?

Comment: Also, do you assume that your extension is *central*, that is, $R$ acts on $A$ trivially? Note that an extension in which $R$ is reductive and $A$ is unipotent splits even without assuming that $A$ is central, and even without assuming that $A$ is abelian. This is Mostow's theorem.

Comment: The last question: How does the Galois group $G$ act on $\mathcal G$? Does it act by  $\Bbb Q$-automorphisms of  the group scheme, or it acts by semilinear automorphisms of ${\mathcal G}\times_{\Bbb Q} \overline{\Bbb Q}$ ?

Comment: After you answer these questions, I can try to construct an obstruction in some second cohomogy group. My experience shows that any cohomology with coefficients in a unipotent group must be trivial, so I expect that any such extension admits a splitting.